# What is the alt+shift+drag shortcut and where can I disable it?

Tags: shortcut-keys, shortcuts, ubuntu-mate, visual-studio-code

I have discovered that the alt+shift+drag shortcut in VS code does not work, and instead moves my window. I have tried in other apps too, and they move the same way, but I didn't find where I can change that shortcut.

What is it? how is it named? how can I disable it?

Comment: What is this question about?

Comment: It is about a shortcut key in ubuntu MATE that I can't find the meaning, and I have no keywords I can use to give me a clue about what is happening.

Comment: In Gnome Shell, Alt is a modifier key to drag windows.

Comment: (Sorry, could not edit my previous comment anymore) It is called "Window Action Key" in gnome tweaks"